# Apache/php return full php error track description

Tags: php, apache, docker, yii

I'm using docker php:7.0-apache (more info in https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) and add my old php code. I'm sending the REST to the web server and got a short description in the track error info.

How could I configure the apache/php to response the whole track info and not just to replace the info with three dots ('...') as below.

Example:

REST response '500 Internal Server Error':
body:

```
CException

SiteController cannot find the requested view "error". (/var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/CController.php:878)

#0 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/CController.php(782): CController->renderPartial('error', Array, true)
#1 /var/www/web_project/protected/controllers/SiteController.php(45): CController->render('error', Array)
#2 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): SiteController->actionError()
#3 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#4 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#5 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#6 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('error')
#7 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(368): CWebApplication->runController('site/error')
#8 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(296): CErrorHandler->renderError()
#9 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(133): CErrorHandler->handleError(Object(CErrorEvent))
#10 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/base/CApplication.php(834): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CErrorEvent))
#11 /var/www/web_project/protected/modules/ioconfig/models/DeviceInstancesTbl.php(47): CApplication->handleError(2, 'Declaration of ...', '/var/www/web_pr...', 47, Array)
#12 /var/www/web_project/protected/modules/systemview/components/UnitsFactory.php(9): require_once('/var/www/web_pr...')
#13 /var/www/web_project/protected/modules/systemview/models/Units.php(13): require_once('/var/www/web_pr...')
#14 /var/www/web_project/protected/modules/systemview/components/SystemviewHelper.php(6): require_once('/var/www/web_pr...')
#15 /var/www/web_project/protected/modules/user_management/controllers/ApiUsermanagementController.php(8): require_once('/var/www/web_pr...')
#16 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(354): require('/var/www/web_pr...')
#17 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(338): CWebApplication->createController('GetGeneralInfo/', Object(User_managementModule))
#18 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(276): CWebApplication->createController('ApiUsermanageme...')
#19 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('user_management...')
#20 /var/www/yii-1.1.17/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#21 /var/www/web_project/index.php(13): CApplication->run()
#22 {main}
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you build & run the image? Instructions would help.

Comment: Just run the docker: docker run php:7.0-apache, I didn't change any configuration and want to understand how to change it and what to change